# how to maintain session for web services using passport.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js for maintaining session and API authentication for web applications and it works fine. Now i want to use my APIs as a web service for android application. My question is my same code will work for web services as I have to maintain session with mobile devices. I am using below code.

```
   app.use(passport.initialize());
   app.use(passport.session());

   passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
     done(null, user._id);
   });

   passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
       done(err, user);
      });
   });
```

and for API authentication i am using middleware

```
app.get("/contentType",user.requiresLogin,  content.selectAllTypes);

exports.requiresLogin = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.status(401).json({error:'User is not authorized'});
  }
  next();
};
```

Comment: You can use Redis for storing session.
https://github.com/tj/connect-redis

Comment: I have to use Passport.js and I want to know if I use my API as a web service then  req.isAuthenticated () will  work? @AnoojKrishnanG K

Comment: If you are maintaining user session correctly req.isAuthenticated() will work.
In case if its not working, save the req.user in REDIS with a key (Encrypted userID (its upto you) ). At the time of logout, remove this data from REDIS.
To check whether user is authenticated or not, check in redis.

Comment: Where you keep the session on the back end is not really the issue here. The issue is in how the session ID will be communicated to the server. In a browser based client the answer is typically cookies, however unless you choose to implement them yourself you will likely not have that option on android. Typically JSON Web Tokens are a good choice for cookie-less clients, but I'm not sure if passport works with those out of the box. You'll probably want to use this too. https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt